# Visual Studio freezing when opening new SQL Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio where when I open it up and go to open up a new query using SQL -> Transact SQL Editor -> New Query Visual Studio becomes unresponsive. The task manager however list it as running, only no buttons are responding. Opening SSMS gives me the same result right when opening it.

One of our network services guys logged into my machine earlier and was able to use everything with no problem so I'm thinking that it might be related a corrupted configuration file I have on my machine. I was wondering if anyone has had this happen before and if there's anyway to resolve it short of a complete reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try resetting the solution settings by deleting the **.suo** file?

Comment: There was no solution open when I tried it, it just started to work yesterday.